# Generate all the possible values using info from random binary tuples (Python)

Tags: python, function, random, tuples

Here's part of the code I'm working on using Python:

```
import random

pairs = [
(0, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 0),
]

alphasori = [(random.choice([1, -1]) * random.uniform(5, 15), pairs[n]) for n in range(4)]

binum = np.random.randint(2, size=4).tolist()
d = dict(zip([0,1,2,3], binum))
alpbi = [(i, tuple(d[j] for j in c)) for i, c in alphasori]
print(alpbi)
```

And this is a sample output (we can call this list as **alpbi**):

```
[(-6.16111614207135, (1, 1)), (-9.39824028732309, (1, 1)), (12.1294338553467, (1, 0)), (8.192565262190904, (0, 1))]
```

I'm now trying to calculate the linear combination (call that **S**) of the random numbers (the first terms) inside each tuple in **alpbi**, (-6.16111614207135,-9.39824028732309...), which is followed by the following rules:

1. if the inner tuple is (1,1) or (0,0), then the random number is multiplied by (-1)
2. if the inner tuple is (0,1) or (1,0), then keep the original number.
3. From 1&2, We're calculating the linear combinations **S** of those random numbers.

For example, for the random sample generated above, we have

S = (-1)*(-6.16111614207135)+ (-1)*(-9.39824028732309) +12.1294338553467+8.192565262190904 = 35.8813

Here's the code I have to figure out a single case:

```
S = 0
for i in range (len(alpbi)):
    if alpbi[i][1][0] == alpbi[i][1][1]:
        S += (-1)*alpbi[i][0]
    else:
        S += alpbi[i][0]
print(S)
```

However, given that '1's and '0's in the inner tuple are random binary numbers, how can I calculate all the possible values of S? (There're 16 combinations, and 8 distinct values in total, I'm wondering is there a way I can write a function to return all the possible values of S at the same time? (like a list containing all of them))

Thanks a lot for reading my question, I really appreciate the help:)

Comment: Shouldn't there be 16 combinations? Since you have 4 numbers in alpbi and each number is associated with a random combination of 0 and 1 that results in either a -1 or +1 factor for the number, you have two different outcomes for each number. This should result in 2^4 = 16 total possibilities .

Comment: @sunnytown Thanks for the comment! There should be 16 combinations, but 8 distinct values:)

Comment: big picture, what are you trying to do? I see your code, but don't understand the goal. What is `S`? What is the expected result in your question?

Comment: @Pierre D Thanks for the comment:) S in my code means a particular linear combination of the random numbers inside each tuple in alpbi (-6.16111614207135, -9.39824028732309, etc.). The goal is to find all the possible values of such linear combinations followed from rule 1 and rule2. There're 8 possible values, and my desired output is a list containing all of them:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be the following:

```
from itertools import product

def all_combinations(numbers):
    linear_combinations = product([-1, 1], repeat=len(numbers))
    result = [sum([a * b for a, b in zip(numbers, factors)]) for factors in linear_combinations]
    return result

alpbi = [(-6.16111614207135, (1, 1)), (-9.39824028732309, (1, 1)), (12.1294338553467, (1, 0)), (8.192565262190904, (0, 1))]
numbers = [item[0] for item in alpbi]

combinations = all_combinations(numbers)
```

However, there are indeed 16 combinations. I assume that when you say there are just 8 distinct value, you mean ignoring the negative pair to the positive one?

In that case you can just filter all negative numbers:

```
combinations = [num for num in combinations if num >= 0]
```